# How to implement min & max date validation in version materialize v1.0.0-rc.2

Tags: materialize

I want to implement min and max date validation(i.e. min date should be less than max date).
I'm using v1.0.0-rc.2 version and I searched the solution, but not found for this version.

Note: I can't change the plugin(version) as it has been used for the entire project.

Please provide me solution only for materialize "v1.0.0-rc.2" version.

Comment: What do you mean by validation? Check this pen -  https://codepen.io/germavinsmoke/pen/MZRpQe?editors=0010#0